# I am training Yolov5. I have labels.txt files that contain 60 labels, but I want to train the model only on 3 classes, how can I do that?

Tags: yolov5

I am training YOLOv5 on xView dataset, and it contains of 60 classes. The label.txt files contains 60 labels. But I want to train the model on only 3 classes to be faster. anyone knows how can I do that. Should I change the name of classes on data.yaml ?

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the classes you don't want to use from the txt files which belongs to images in datasets. (You can write a shell script to do it) Modify the label.txt and data.yaml with your new (3 classes) situation. It should be work.